# Why does a C++ mathematical operation accept a letter as an input and output a number?

Tags: c++, user-input

I'm brand new to c++, so maybe this is a stupid question, but I coded a very simple temperature conversion program. It looks like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  
  double tempf;
  double tempc;
  
  // Ask the user
  std::cout << "Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: ";
  std::cin >> tempf;
  
  // Conversion
  tempc = (tempf - 32) / 1.8;
  
  // Print Output  
  std::cout << "The temp is " << tempc << " degrees Celsius.\n";
  
}
```

This compiles and runs fine when I enter an integer/float as an input. However, out of curiosity, I tried entering a letter, expecting to get an error or a failure of some kind. Instead, after compiling, I get this output:

```
$ g++ temperature.cpp -o temp
$ ./temp
Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: abc
The temp is -17.7778 degrees Celsius.
```

Can someone tell me where the executable is getting the output `-17.7778` from? This seems like an arbitrary number, not a mathematical output.

Comment: `std::cin >> tempf;` doesn't check if the operation was successful.  If not successful, `tempf` is set to 0 in more recent C++ standards.  To check for failure: `if (!(std::cin >> tempf)) throw std::runtime_error("failure");`

Comment: You should check the return value of `std::cin >> tempf;` before accessing  `tempf`.

Comment: You didn't actually check if the input was accepted or not. You can use `if(std::cin)` to check if an input succeeded or failed. Newer versions of c++ default to assigning 0 on failure, so you get `-32/1.8` which is `-17.777`.

Comment: Variable `tempf` just retains (preserves) its previous value (which is not provided as part of your code, which therefore yields undefined behavior, meaning that it may hold different values when executed on different platforms, or even over different executions on the same platform).

Comment: This is the reason it's often recommended to read *whole lines* of input into a string, and then attempt to parse the string. For example using [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof).

Comment: You can also use `std::cin.getline` to read the input characters and write them to a buffer and then use `std::from_chars` to convert it to `double`.

Comment: (0 - 32) / 1.8 does indeed equal -17.7778, so this seems to be the solution, thank you all

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb `std::cin` assigns zero on failure, or a limit value if it fails due to out of bounds input. `tempf` is not unspecified after `std::cin` even if it fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"However, out of curiosity, I tried entering a letter, expecting to get an error or a failure of some kind."*

By default, `std::cin` reports errors by setting internal error bits that must be checked manually. One mechanism is to use the `good()` member function to check for any error bits. Another is to use the `bool` conversion operator which does the same thing, it will convert to `true` is no error bits are set, otherwise it converts to `false`.

Example :

```
if(!std::cin) {
    std::cout << "Input error!";
    return;
}
```

When `std::cin` fails, it will assign the value 0 to the variable.

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) :

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), zero is written to value and failbit is set.

When you provide the input `"abc"` the expression `std::cin >> tempf;` will fail to read anything, assign `0` to `tempf` and set a fail bit. Then, during `tempc = (tempf - 32) / 1.8;` the value calculated will be `(0.0 - 32) / 1.8` which is approximately `-17.7778` which is the result you observe.

You can change the default behavior to throw an exception on failure by using the `exceptions` member function. But beware that if other parts of your project use `std::cin` and don't expect this change it can disrupt their error handling scheme which may rely on checking error bits.

The example provided by [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions#Example) for this example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
 
int main() 
{
    int ivalue;
    try {
        std::ifstream in("in.txt");
        in.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit); // may throw
        in >> ivalue; // may throw
    } catch (const std::ios_base::failure& fail) {
        // handle exception here
        std::cout << fail.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```